# Why does fgetc function add a carriage return

Tags: c

I'm reading a TXT file made of chars and writing the ASCII values of those chars to output.txt.

Any time I read char number 10 in ASCII table (Line Feed), I get 13 then 10 instead of 10 in my output file.
(13 means Carriage Return in ASCII )

Here is my code:

```
 in_file = fopen(FILE_NAME, "rb");
...
  while((ch = fgetc(in_file)) != EOF){
    count++;
    fprintf(p, "%d\n", ch);
  }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The input file has been formatted with Windows line breaks, which are the pair of characters of `\r\n`.  UNIX text files only have `\n`.  Your output is therefore correct.

Comment: @user2080006: Either you filter out the \r yourself. Or you use an external tool, like `dos2unix`. Or open the output file in binary mode as well, instead of text mode...

Comment: thanks, but I use this values in automatic test .
there is a way to solve it into my .c code ?

Comment: Well, you haven't really explained what you're actually doing - it seems that you read in a file and then write it out to another file.  Are you trying to count the lines, or split them or something?  Also please state which platform you are using.

Comment: I try to convert the ASCII char to ASCII value , each by new line
I am using win. XP and CODE BLOCKS compiler

Comment: OK - but in that case, the *correct* output for an ASCII file with Windows line breaks would be "13 10" at the end of every line.  Are you saying you want to suppress the carriage returns anyway, even though they are in your source file?

Comment: I change part of my code to handle this case:
    if(ch == 13){
        ch = fgetc(in_file);
        if(ch != 10)
            fprintf(p, "13\n");
            fprintf(p, "%d\n", ch);}
    else{
        fprintf(p, "%d\n", ch);
    }
thanks you all !

Answer (score 1):

Character 10 is a linefeed (`\n`); character 13 is a carriage return (`\r`).  Windows line terminators are typically a carriage return followed by a linefeed.  On UNIX/Linux, the line terminator is typically just a linefeed.  On Mac OS it used to be just a carriage return IIRC, but that may no longer be the case with OS X (since it's UN*X under the hood).

The file may have been created on a Windows system, as noted by @jazzbassrob.
Or, if you're running on a Windows system, I believe some implementations of the I/O library functions will translate UNIX-style line terminators into Windows style.

So, as other posters have noted, the output is probably correct.

EDIT:
Try removing the `b` from the call to `fopen()`; that opens the file in binary mode.  In "text" mode -- i.e. `fopen(FILE_NAME, "r")` -- `fgetc()` may discard the carriage return.

EDIT 2:
In text mode, line terminators should be "normalized" to a newline (as @DevSolar points out).  If, on the other hand, you open a file in binary mode, you shouldn't assume or rely on a particular character being the line terminator.  (Unless you control creation of the input file, you're specifically concerned with converting from one format to the other, etc.)

Comment: The C standard specifies \n as the line terminator. Opening a file in text mode should make any platform-specific line terminator transparent to the application. Then again, that's the theory. And the OP did *not* open the input file in text mode (and neither did he tell us which OS he's running on).

Comment: Initially I assumed the binary flag was intentional.  I realized that assumption might have been wrong and was editing my response when you commented ;)

Comment: if I change mode from "rb" to "r", when I receive EOF the loop is break

Comment: Not sure I understand the comment.  EOF isn't supposed to be treated like a regular character -- there may be an end-of-file character on a particular OS, but you shouldn't assume that's the case -- it's a condition (there's no more information to be read from the file).

Answer (score 0):

You read the carriage return ( `0x0d` ), becouse you read the file in binary mode `"rb"`, this way fgetc() will read every char including `0x0d` followed by `0x0a` ( carriage return ).

If you open the file as text `"r"`, fgetc() will skip the `0x0d` if followed by `0x0a` and display only `0x0a`.

Comment: Opening the input file as text would only make a difference on a Windows/DOS system. UNIX systems treat both modes the same...

Comment: there is a way to read a txt file made of chars without using binary mode? 
I thave tried this first but any time that fgetc receive EOF my while loop broke

Comment: @user2080006: "Any time"? fgetc() should recieve EOF (end-of-file, -1) exactly *once*, when it reached the end of the file - in which case, your loop *should* end. And binary vs. text mode shouldn't change anything in this case.